# Can ubuntu be installed on VMWare?

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-fusion

I have attempted to install both 12.4 and 12.10 on both Fusion 5 and VMware Player without anything related to success.

With Fusion, it crashes at login attempt, with VMware Player, it crashes during install.

No error logs (that I know of) just abject failure.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes" and "abject failure"? Do you mean it freezes up and does not respond? That it mysteriously shuts down or reboots?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have successfully installed various versions of Ubuntu on VMware products, both Fusion and Workstation. Therefore, if you are unable to install Ubuntu on a virtual environment, I don't think the cause of problem is Ubuntu itself, but I would blame the virtual environment or/and the product in use, such as VMware Player. Make sure you are using the latest version of the product, and that it is updated.

When setting up the virtual machine, you must make sure that the system requirements are met, also the allocated RAM on the VM should be the double of the recommended.

Some information on the community wiki:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware